# Server 2012r2 RDS - Start Screen

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, rds

I'm in the process of setting up an RDS server.  It will be multi-tenant, so it's locked right down. All user profile data is stored on the file server using GPO folder redirection.

I want to lock the start screen right down to only show what they have access to: Office,  our application, "This PC", Desktop, Notepad and Calculator.

I have logged as an admin user and configured a start screen to suit. Used `Export-StartLayout` to get my layout XML. I have set the use start layout GPO to the user share where it is located.

**The issue is:**

I can't get all the apps to show on the start screen. Office shows fine, but our app won't show along with notepad and  "this PC".
A little stuck on this one...

**Layout.XML**

```xml
<launcher version="2">
  <view name="Start">
    <group name="Desktop">
      <tile AppID="{C9BAE21F-221E-405F-BA9D-FAC741829F4F}\Office Companion.lnk" size="square150x150" FencePost="0" />
      <tile AppID="Chrome" size="square150x150" FencePost="0" />
      <tile AppID="{1AC14E77-02E7-4E5D-B744-2EB1AE5198B7}\notepad.exe" size="square150x150" FencePost="0" />
      <tile AppID="Microsoft.Windows.Computer" size="square150x150" FencePost="0" />
      <tile AppID="Microsoft.Windows.Desktop" size="square150x150" FencePost="0" />
    </group>
    <group name="Microsoft Office">
      <tile AppID="{7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}\Microsoft Office\Office15\ONENOTE.EXE" size="square150x150"  FencePost="0" />
      <tile AppID="Microsoft.Office.OUTLOOK.EXE.15" size="square150x150" FencePost="0" />
      <tile AppID="{7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE" size="square150x150"
      FencePost="0" />
      <tile AppID="{7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE" size="square150x150"
      FencePost="0" />
    </group>
  </view>
</launcher>
```

Comment: Before I give you my answer on this, can you try logging in as a regular (standard) user with no admin creds and exporting the XML again?  Then use it on the GPO as you mentioned.  I think that may be all that you were having trouble with.

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to try what I suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was our app is not "installed", it is just a shortcut to some files.  I created a launcher and installed that. IT now shows up.

Answer (score 1):

[This references Windows 8/8.1, but applies to 2012/R2.](http://trekker.net/archives/control-the-windows-8-1-start-screen-layout-with-group-policy/)  Be sure to read to the bottom as there are some great QAs for things like you're experiencing where not everything shows up.  I've included a screenshot for reference, but basically when users don't see all the tiles/apps it's *USUALLY* because of three major things:

**A) You didn't apply the layout to the default profile**

**B) You didn't install/configure a custom app, or third party app, correctly on the computer in question, and the computer doesn't recognize it as being installed locally.**

**C) Permissions used to export/import the XML/start layout.**

[image]

Comment: Whilst this did now solve my issue, it is certainly worth reading  - very relevant to managing the Start Screen.